# Passing a GET variable back in a query while using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: ee2, database, query, mysql, api

I'm trying to take a variable that's passed in a query string (GET) and then use that variable to do a SELECT based on it...

```
// Assign query string to a variable while sanitizing it against XSS
$event = ee()->input->get_post('event', TRUE);

// Build query
$sql = "SELECT t.entry_id
    FROM exp_channel_titles t
    LEFT join exp_channel_data d
    ON t.entry_id = d.entry_id
    WHERE
        field_id_42 LIKE '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($event) . "';";

// Execute query
$query  = ee()->db->query( "$sql" );
```

It executes as expected, however I am seeing the following error in the error log:

`Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

What is the 'EE way' to pass the [required connection parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to the mysqli_real_escape_string() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ee()->db->escape_str($event)` - it's the native way to escape potentially-unsafe data in EE.